# linkedin + file_get_contents() failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to post in linkedin group via php file (actually I want to do this thing by cron)

error is : file_get_contents(https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/group_id/posts?oauth2_access_token=xxxxxxx&format=json&content=%7B%22title%22%3A%22my+title+%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22my+Summery++%22%7D)

: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/html/linkedin_update/xyz.php on line 161

kindly guide me how to fix this thing ...

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Is the access token (still) valid?

Comment: I think you need to put the actual group id in place of `group_id`.

Comment: And posting contents should be `POST` request, as said here - http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#create.

Comment: yes Jack access token still valid ...

Comment: Bibhas I am already putting actual group id .... here just for purpose I am showing group_id ..

Comment: my posting content in post format already ... here it shows in error (notice) ..